Kaggle is not rendering bullet point in R Markdown
So I am trying to finish up this case study for the google data analytics but, the bullet point in my R Markdown script wont render. I tried adding new lines before and after each bullet but it didnt help.
Here is a snippet of my script
# Prepare

* Where is the data being stored?

    + The original data files are being stored in an AWS S3 Bucket at [this link](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html). <br/> The downloaded datafiles are then uploaded to kaggle cloud storage.

* How is the data organized?

    + The provided data files are in the CSV file format and all 12 contain the same 13 column names.

* How was data integrity verified?

    + The document outling the case study provided a link to a secure AWS S3 Bucket.<br/> The link to AWS S3 is provided by google which by many is considered a credible source of data.

* Will this data help answer the business question being asked?

    + The data provided contains all the information needed to answer the business questions being asked

* Are there problems with the data?

    + There are a few problems:

        - started_at and ended_at date columns have dates in different formats

        - some of the latitude and longitude coordinates do not coincide with a start_station_name or an end_station_name


In RStudio the R Markdown script renders as I expect but in kaggle I get this

You can see my entire script here:
https://gist.github.com/pmartinez8241/22179f4f2f67311110fc70d37f908067

I am a total noob at R and kaggle!
I had the setting configured as an R script, but I wanted an R Notebook! I set the editor type to R Notebook and everything is now working as expected.
